# highcharts send an array to series data

Tags: highcharts

I use highcharts and angular

I have an api which return a string **taskLbl** of name concatenate with comma  : `'test1','test2'`

also an api which return a string **taskNbr** of name concatenate with comma : `'1','2'`

I want to send an object to `data: [  of series: [{`

I try with this code :

```ts
public getValue(taskLbl:any,taskNbr:any)
{
    const colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;
    var objects =[];

    const arraylbl = taskLbl.split(',');
    const arrayNbr = taskNbr.split(',');

    for (var i = 0; i < arraylbl.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arrayNbr.length; j++) {
            objects.push([
                '{'+ 'name: '+''+arraylbl[i],
                'y:' +arrayNbr[j],
                'color:'+''+colors[i]+'}'
            ]);
        }
    }
    this.fillData(objects);

    Highcharts.chart('container', this.options);
}

/*
 fill fillData
 */
public fillData(objects:any)
{
    this.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 45
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'stat'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                innerSize: 100,
                depth: 45
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'number',
            data: [
                objects
            ]
        }],
    }
}
```

first create array from the first array of name and the second array of number and send it to data of HighCharts

but I have two problem :

the first one :  **objects** add duplicate value meaning the result is :

```
{name: test1,y:1,color:#7cb5ec},
{name: test1,y:1,color:#7cb5ec},
{name: test2,y:2,color:#434348},
{name: test2,y:2,color:#434348}
```

and the correct result should be

```
{name: test1,y:1,color:#7cb5ec},
{name: test2,y:2,color:#434348},
```

and the second problem that I have this error

```
Error: <rect> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN".
```

and to solve the problem the **objects** should be like this :

```
{name: 'test1',y:1,color:'#7cb5ec'},
{name: 'test2',y:2,color:'#434348'}
```

meaning value of name should have a **single quotes** same thing with value of color

how to obtain an array with this kind of output.

can someone help me to create a correct object to send it to highcharts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you have duplicates in your `objects` variable, that is certainly caused by duplicates in either `arraylbl` or `arrayNbr` (or both). It is thus more efficient to eliminate duplicates at source. You can implement a function that filters out duplicates:

```ts
function unique<T>(a: Array<T>): Array<T>{
  return a.filter((x,i,a)=>a.indexOf(x)===i);
}
```

and apply it when the two arrays are built:

```ts
    // .......
    const arraylbl = unique(taskLbl.split(','));
    const arrayNbr = unique(taskNbr.split(',').map(parseFloat));
```

I also applied the function `parseFloat` to extract the numeric value from its string representation, since you want `y` in the `objects` variable sent to highcharts to be a number.

Now the main issue is the objects array - in highcharts the value of `series.data` (at least for type pie), should be an array of *objects*. Your code makes it an array of arrays of strings.

You have to modify the code inside your double `for` loop this way:

```ts
    for (let i = 0; i < arraylbl.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arrayNbr.length; j++) {
            objects.push({
                name: arraylbl[i],
                y: arrayNbr[j],
                color: colors[i]
            });
        }
    }
```

This should work, but I'm not sure that this is exactly what you wanted. I don't know your data and the context, but this full combination of all pairs on a single pie, with adjacent slices of the same name and different `y`s having the same color seems unusual. You may want to represent your data on a multi-level doughnut chart like [in this example](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut) or possibly a pie with drilldown like [this one](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-drilldown). I won't go into those yet, since it's unlikely to get right that much code without being able to test it, but if you add a working example with some data in a codesandbox or stackblitz, I or someone else on this site will help you in that direction.